# Set Custom Save Dialog Attributes

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I am looking at the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) but I do not see any way of allowing users to set custom attributes. Does anyone know how I can prompt the user for custom attributes at the same time.

The screenshot below is from Excel 2010 and is doing exactly what I would like to accomplish.

[image: Custom Window Properties]

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Build your own form....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that without "extending" the `SaveFileDialog` or creating your own form.

I've found a few links you may find interesting:

> [Adding a control to a SaveFileDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8086/Extending-the-save-file-dialog-class-in-NET)
>
> [Extending OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy)

They do seem "hackish" though.

Here are a few user controls that may help you if you decide to roll up your own form, though it's a pity if you really have to "reinvent" the wheel.

> [Explorer Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14570/A-Windows-Explorer-in-a-user-control)
>
> [FileBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser)

Good Luck.

Comment: It is a shame I was hoping to avoid that path, but it looks like this is what I would have to do.